# oracle.manageddataaccess.client duplicate entry for ASP:NET

Tags: asp.net, oracle, duplicates, odp.net

Hy,

I am working on an asp.net web application.
I have downloaded the latest version of ODP.NET to perform DB-activities.
Now i am facing the following error:
**There is a duplicate 'oracle.manageddataaccess.client' section defined**

I already tried the workaround solution to delete the section in the machine.config file, without success (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odpnet-managed-nuget-121021-2405792.txt).

Does anybody know any other possiblity to solve this issue?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script to remove all entries:

```
set Oracle_x64=c:\oracle\product\12.1\Client_x64\odp.net
set Oracle_x86=c:\oracle\product\12.1\Client_x86\odp.net

set OraProvCfg_x64=%Oracle_x64%\bin\4\OraProvCfg
set OraProvCfg_x86=%Oracle_x86%\bin\4\OraProvCfg


"OraProvCfg_x64" /action:config /force /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.121.1.0 /unset:settings\TNS_ADMIN
"OraProvCfg_x64" /action:config /force /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.121.2.0 /unset:settings\TNS_ADMIN
"OraProvCfg_x64" /action:config /force /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.122.1.0 /unset:settings\TNS_ADMIN
"OraProvCfg_x64" /action:config /force /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.122.18.3 /unset:settings\TNS_ADMIN
"OraProvCfg_x64" /action:unconfig /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.121.1.0
"OraProvCfg_x64" /action:unconfig /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.121.2.0
"OraProvCfg_x64" /action:unconfig /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.122.1.0
"OraProvCfg_x64" /action:unconfig /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.122.18.3

"OraProvCfg_x86" /action:config /force /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.121.1.0 /unset:settings\TNS_ADMIN
"OraProvCfg_x86" /action:config /force /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.121.2.0 /unset:settings\TNS_ADMIN
"OraProvCfg_x86" /action:config /force /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.122.1.0 /unset:settings\TNS_ADMIN
"OraProvCfg_x86" /action:config /force /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.122.18.3 /unset:settings\TNS_ADMIN
"OraProvCfg_x86" /action:unconfig /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.121.1.0
"OraProvCfg_x86" /action:unconfig /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.121.2.0
"OraProvCfg_x86" /action:unconfig /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.122.1.0
"OraProvCfg_x86" /action:unconfig /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.122.18.3
```

Afterwards you can use the same tool to configure it properly:

```
set TNS_ADMIN=C:\oracle\network\admin

IF EXIST "%Oracle_x64%\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:config /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll /set:settings\TNS_ADMIN:%TNS_ADMIN%
IF EXIST "%Oracle_x86%\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:config /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll /set:settings\TNS_ADMIN:%TNS_ADMIN%
```

**Update**

Actually you can remove all entries shorter with

```
set Oracle_x64=c:\oracle\product\12.1\Client_x64\odp.net
set Oracle_x86=c:\oracle\product\12.1\Client_x86\odp.net

set OraProvCfg_x64=%Oracle_x64%\bin\4\OraProvCfg
set OraProvCfg_x86=%Oracle_x86%\bin\4\OraProvCfg

"OraProvCfg_x86" /action:unconfig /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319
"OraProvCfg_x64" /action:unconfig /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319
```